# How to find limit of this function: $\lim_{n\to\infty} 0.99\ldots99^{10^n}$?

Tags: limits, exponential-function

How to find this limit:

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}  0.99\ldots99^{10^n},$$

$$ \text{where number of 9 is } n. $$

My solution:
$$ \text{if } n\to\infty \text{ then } 0.99\ldots99 \to\ 0.(9) $$
$$ \text{because } 0.(9) = 1 \implies \lim_{n\to\infty}  0.99\ldots99^{10^n}=1^{10^\infty} = 1 $$

But my solution is wrong. Why? How can I correct it?

Comment: What is the answer?

Comment: I don't know. It is a test with an input form of online course, so the solution is exactly not 1...

Comment: Same reason $\lim_{n\to\infty} (1+1/n)^n = e \neq 1$

Comment: How did you get $ (1 + 1/n)^n $ ? Can you write the solution as the answer ?

Comment: I was just pointing out the flaw in your reasoning. If the base goes to one, but the exponent also grows, then you can't necessarily say the limit approaches $1$.

Comment: Note that $0.99..99 = 1 - \frac{1}{10^n}$ so
$$\log (\lim_{n\to\infty} 0.99...99^{10^n}) = \lim_{n\to\infty} 10^n \log \left(1 - \frac{1}{10^n}\right) = \lim_{n\to\infty} 10^n \left(-\frac{1}{10^n} + O(10^{-2n}) \right) = -1. $$
Now fill in the gaps.

Comment: Note the proper use of \text{} in MathJax, as in my edit to the question.

Comment: You're not just letting the number of $9$s increase; you're also raising that number to a very large power. Consider $\displaystyle \left( 1 - \frac 1 n \right)^n \to \frac 1 e \text{ as } n\to\infty.$ The form $1^\infty$ is indeterminate; i.e. if $a\to 1$ and $b\to\infty$ then $a^b$ could aproach any positive number or $0$ or $+\infty$ depending on how $a$ and $b$ depend on each other.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The limit you're trying to find is

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} (1-10^{-n})^{10^n} $$

Substitute $u \mapsto 10^n$ and you get

$$ \lim_{u\to\infty} \left(1-\frac 1 u \right)^u = \frac 1 e $$

Answer (score -1):

Your answer is wrong because 1 to the power infinity is not equal to 1 but it has unspecified value just like 0/0